# how to change font color in wiki on github

Tags: github, styles, wiki

I can't change font color in wiki on github. 
`<div style="color: red">test</div>`
`<font color="red">test</font>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunetly, You cannot include style directives in [GFM](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).

Here is the most complete "[Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)", and it shows that this element `<style>` is missing.

That being said, you can use diff code style highlighting for red and green:

````
```diff
+ this will be highlighted in green
- this will be highlighted in red
```
````

Comment: I not want have "+ hola"